# Command Execution With Arguments Have No Relation with Stdin?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, input

Here is a script to check what the source is for stdin,

which is from How-to Geek: "What Are stdin, stdout, and stderr on Linux?"

https://www.howtogeek.com/435903/what-are-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-on-linux/

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -t 0 ]; then

  echo stdin coming from keyboard

else

  echo stdin coming from a pipe or a file

fi
```

Then if any command is executed with arguments or the command substitution, does it have no relation with `stdin`? In such case, is the `stdin` empty?

And although I can understand the meaning of `stdin` coming from a pipe or a file, but what is the meaning of `stdin` coming from keyboard? Is it one like key typing for `read` command or here document?

Thank the community for its everyday's support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To demystify the difference between `command line arguments` and `stdin`. I am going to divide my answer into multiple parts explaining the underling concepts. Then answer your question.

Before I start explaining, do keep the following things in mind:

1. In Linux everything is considered as a file.
2. I assume you have read the entire post provided in the question.
3. I am going to take help of C program to explain the difference, therefore I assume you know basic syntax. Still I will explain as much as I can.

## stdin and command line arguments

Standard Input is a file Linux which is accessed by programs to take input from the user. Any program cannot directly interact with Keyboard instead they interact with `stdin`. So if a program needs to take an input from user it will access `stdin`.

When you use redirection (`> or <`) or pipe (`|`) it with other command it manipulates the input and output steams, i.e `stdin` and `stdout`. When you specify these special characters they instruct `stdin` and `stdout` how to function. In Linux, `stdin` is `/proc/self/fd/0` , and `stdout` is `/proc/self/fd/1`

Command line arguments are basically a method to take input from used along with the invocation of command to make the command do some specific task. **It is not necessary for each and every program to have command line arguments**, as it is up to the developer of the following program to use them.

Command line arguments are passed to a command as an array. ( *Array is a data structure consisting of a collection of elements, each identified by at least one array index or key.* ). Hence the values in that array can be used by the programmer to add more functionality to their program.

### Examples of C Program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc==2) 
        printf("Welcome Master %s\n", argv[1]);
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s <name>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, the program does not take any standard input from user however it does take command line arguments and works differently depending upon the argument is provided or not.

`argc` is a variable which stores the count of arguments passed and `argv` is an array which stores the arguments passed while invoking the program. `argv[0]` is the first element in the array which contains the name of the program itself. After that array will contain the arguments passed.

When I execute the following program by typing "./batman", I get following output:

> Usage : ./batman

But when I execute the same program by typing "./batman Bruce". I get :

> Welcome Master Bruce

Now this does not mean this program cannot take input. Below is modified program which takes both command line argument and standard input.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pass = 0;
    if(argc==2){
        printf("Welcome Master %s\n", argv[1]);
        printf("Kindly provide password : ");
        scanf("%d", &pass);
        if(pass==1234)
            printf("Batcave Access granted\n");
        else
            printf("Batcave Access declined\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s <name>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above takes a command line argument then wait for user to enter password through standard input.
If we don't specify any argument it will throw an error just like in previous C code.
Below is the output when program is executed :

> ```
> mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ ./batman3 Bruce
> Welcome Master Bruce
> Kindly provide password : 1234
> Batcave Access granted
> mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$ ./batman3 Joker
> Welcome Master Joker
> Kindly provide password : 123
> Batcave Access declined
> mars@HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/Practice/cpp$
> ```

After passing the command line argument this program waited for password which was supposed to be entered by the user, hence through `stdin`

### What is the conclusion then?

I hope you understood the concepts I explained above. Now time to answer those questions.

1. Yes, command line arguments have no relation with `stdin` and `stdin` in that case is just pointing to your input device but not being used.
2. `stdin` is itself is a file which by default points to your input device and takes input from there. However when you provide pipe or redirection in your command it tells the `stdin` to take input from the file you specified instead of input device attached to you computer.

If you didn't understand the C program it's alright. This time lets use an in-built command instead of custom made program.

Example of command instead of program:

```
cat file_name
cat < file_name
```

the output will be identical because the corresponding developer makes `cat` to either read data from `stdin` or read the data from the file, whose name is given as the first command line argument (which is the first element in the array the shell passes to cat).

Subsequently cat writes the whole content of file_name or `stdin` to the terminal since we don't instruct the shell to manipulate `stdout`. Remember that in the second line your shell manipulates `stdin` in this way, that it doesn't point to your standard input device any longer but points to a file called file_name in your current working directory. [This example was taken from another post, you can click here to read more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46372/whats-the-difference-between-stdin-and-arguments-passed-to-command)

I hope this not only provided you with the solution to the question but also helped you understand the underlying concepts.

Comment: In addition to the privious question, you have provided support to me. Thank you! At first glance, these description seems rather difficult. So I will try to understand line by line.

Comment: I have finishied reading and understood, it may be not 100% though. I sometimes face difficulty to use pipeline, so I wanted to understand stdin. I think the knowledge you have provided here will help me! Anyway, I have no Programing language experiece. But the sample code you have shown here seems a bit similar to shell scrips of Bash. I have practiced Bash scripts, which helps me to understand what you are explaining. This time's you support have given me the knowledge and the interest in the C programming. I really appriciate your supports!

Comment: @CaptainCookie it's alright, the community was made to support each other and to learn & grow together. Still if there is anything you don't understand feel free to ask away